# Imagebox doesn't redraw

Tags: vba, powerpoint, userform

I have two user forms (Frm1,Frm2), each one has an imagebox (Img1,Img2) and a button (Btn1,Btn2) on it, and then I have two jpegs (jpg1,jpg2), please download my sample, a PowerPoint macro [here](http://goo.gl/X5PvI)

The steps:

1. run "main" and the Frm1 shows up (vbmodal)
2. click Btn1 to switch jpg1 and jpg2 on Img1
3. click Img1 to show Frm2 vbmodal, and Img2 should show same jpg as Img1
4. click Btn2 to unload Frm2
5. (problem) click Btn1 to switch jpg but cannot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
Me.Repaint
```

after `Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(strpic)` in `UserForm1` >> `CommandButton1_Click()`